# word-wrap: break-word doesn't work in IE 11 & FF 57 with ReactJS & RadiumJS

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, radium

I've been searching the web for a solution to this problem but couldn't find any info for this. Hope someone here will know what )'m talking about.

**The problem is with IE 11 & FireFox 56**

- Im using **ReactJs** for View.
- Im using **RadiumJs** for inline styling.

Now I have a text paragraph, and a very long word the doesn't break - I'm using `word-break: break-word`.

[image: long word that does not break]

I do know that it could work if I add  `-ms-word-break: break-word`, but I couldn't find how to add this with Radium.

#### How can I break long words in IE & FF while using RadiumJS?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have an example of this working elsewhere? I just tested on Chrome with React and Radium and a whole line of `00000...` didn't wrap with `word-break: break-word`

Comment: i can't post here an image but you should see the line of 0's breaks and ending with "1222"